# How to pass data from one controller to another (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, session, controller, session-variables

I'm trying to make a google connection system in a Laravel API with a VueJS Front.

I've got multiple ways of connection, one being the connection to the website where this application will be embedded, the other will be with Google or another external way (Github...)

For the first method, I'm using the Memcached data to recover the connected user and send it to the front (I just need the mail and the name).

In Laravel, I'm using Session data to store the user:

```
  if (isset($_SESSION['firstname']) && isset($_SESSION['lastname']) && isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
           $user = new User([
             'origin' => 'mel',
             'name' => $_SESSION['firstname'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['lastname'],
             'email' => $_SESSION['email'],
           ]);
        }

Session::put('user', $user);
```

This part is called in the global controller.

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
  use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
  
  public function __construct()
  {
    Session::sessionConnect();
  }
}
```

And then I send It in an API request:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    return response()->json(Session::get('user'));
  }
}
```

This system is working fine but the problem is with the Google Connection. After the connection with Google, I'm using the same system to put a user in the session:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
 public function googleConnection()
  {
   // After getting data from Google
      $user = new User([
         'origin' => 'google',
         'name' => $oidc->requestUserInfo('name'),
         'email' => $oidc->requestUserInfo('email'),
         'picture' => $oidc->requestUserInfo('picture'),
       ]);
   Session::put('user', $user);
  }
}
```

But in this case, the UserController can't find this data stored in the session.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Your authentication seems strange to me, you create a user out of thin air and store it in session ? You don't have any users table ? Usually user is recovered using : `auth()->user()` . It seems to me that you are not using laravel auth at all

Comment: I'm not using Laravel for the authentification (sorry if it's not clear) I'm just using it to send the user data (from the top application or Google) to the VueJs Front.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing ? but assume the first bit of code is somewhere other than LoginController? why not create a service class and defer to it from where ever you  need to ? 
```` $service = app(LoginWithGoogle::class); $service->logIn($firstName, $lastName, $email); ````
 and getting a session is just that from anywhere